# In R, I am trying to loop through variables of lists and pull out a specific index from each one

Tags: r, loops, indexing

In R, I am using `readHTMLTable` to read in a tables from the web. The tables I want occur at indexes 16 & 17, `[[16]]` & `[[17]]`.

Here is a small sample of the data for you to work with:

These are some of the urls that contain the HTML tables.

```
url1 = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1980.html"
url2 = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1981.html"
url3 = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1982.html"
```

And here, I read in the tables to variables named x1, x2, and x3.

```
x1 = readHTMLTable(url1)
x2 = readHTMLTable(url2)
x3 = readHTMLTable(url3)
```

If you look at the summary of each of these `summary(x1)`, `summary(x2)`, `summary(x3)` and count down through the indexes, the tables I want are the ones named "team" and "opponent", which occur on line 16 and line 17.

I have been trying to write a loop that would cycle through these and name the "team" table from each to a variables named `team.1980`, `team.1981`, and `team.1982`, respectively. The "opponent" tables would follow the same trend, `opp.1980`, and so forth.

This is the code for the loop I have been trying:

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1980:1982) {
    nam1 = paste0("team.", j)
    nam2 = paste0("opp.", j)
    assign(nam1, paste0("x.", i)[[16]])
    assign(nam2, paste0("x.", i)[[17]])
  }
}
```

I think the theory behind this loop works, however the problem occurs with the two `assign` functions:

```
assign(nam1, paste0("x.", i)[[16]])
assign(nam2, paste0("x.", i)[[17]])
```

When I run the loop, I get the error message

```
Error in paste0("x.", i)[[16]] : subscript out of bounds
```

which is the same error I get if I just run:

```
paste0("x", 1)[[16]]

> paste0("x", 1)[[16]]
  Error in paste0("x", 1)[[16]] : subscript out of bounds
```

So I am pretty sure this is where my problem is. Does anyone know how I could cycle through variables and pull out indexes from each?

Please keep in mind that I am rather new to R, so simplicity would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're getting a subscript error because `paste0("x", 1)` is just a string; there's nothing to index. The syntax `[[16]]` is trying to access the 16th item from `paste0(...)` as a list, but it's not a list, it's just a string.

Comment: You got an error in your paste statements. Your paste results in x.1[[16]], which doesn't exist and hence you get a subscript out of bounds.
Here's the corrected section of your code `for(i in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1980:1983) {
        nam1 = paste0("team.", j)
        nam2 = paste0("opp.", j)
        assign(nam1, paste0("x", i,"[[16]]"))
        assign(nam2, paste0("x", i,"[[17]]"))
    }
}`

Comment: you need one more iteration in your loop. `for (i in 1:4)`

Comment: The double loop doesn't make sense--you only need one loop to get what you're after.

Comment: yup! I just tried fixing his paste statement! His whole loop is wrong!

Comment: @plafort: No data has been defined in the post for 1983, so looping to 4 will cause an error.

Comment: @infominer: Yep. I think I got it all sorted out in my answer though. At least it works for me.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I put that loop to run to 1983, that was just a mistake in my example. That was not wrong in my actual data. Yes, Alex, your are correct that I am trying to pull an index from a string, I realize that. I was hoping someone knew a better way to do it. I need the double loop to name my variable names that I want to define (for the way that I was envisioning doing it anyways).

Comment: A great link for writing faster code `@Matt Collins` [Faster Code](http://quanttrader.info/public/FasterRCode.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `readHTMLTable()` is a list and the elements can be referenced by name; index isn't necessary. (Though you can use it.)

Suppose `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` are defined as in your post. Then you can just do this:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    year <- 1980 + i - 1
    eval(parse(text=paste0("team.", year, " <- x", i, '[["team"]]')))
    eval(parse(text=paste0("opp.", year, " <- x", i, '[["opponent"]]')))
}
```

This evaluates the parsed text that's constructed dynamically in the loop. It creates 6 data frames: `team.1980` and `opp.1980` for years 1980-1982.

Let's take a closer look at what it's doing...

First a string is constructed using `paste0()` to concatenate the values into a string with no separator. The first call to `paste0()` in the first iteration yields this string:

```
'team.1980 <- x1[["team"]]'
```

Calling `parse()` on this tells R to turn that string into an object called an *expression*. Expressions can be evaluated using `eval()`. So this string gets turned into an R statement and executed, thereby assigning `team.1980`.

This process continues for each of the 3 iterations.

This may not be the best approach, but it should work in your situation. I assume you have more than just these 6, otherwise you might as well just write them as individual assignments.

Comment: use 4 iterations to go to 1983

Comment: @plafort: If you look in the post, only data for 1980-1982 has been defined. (There's no `x4` corresponding to 1983.)

Comment: Yes, I realized I miscounted the number of years in my example above, but that was not causing the error as I did not do that in my actual data.

Comment: Alex, your answer above is exactly what I was looking for. I think that should do that trick! As I said, I am new to R, I figured there was a way to evaluate a string of text, I was just not aware of parse and eval, at least how they were used. I am going to try this but I think it should work perfectly. Thanks! and thanks everyone for your posts!